# Why is gulp cssnano failing?

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I get this error:

```
 this.processing = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
```

When I try to:

```
gulp.task('site-css', function() {
    return gulp.src(cssconfig.src)
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(concat('sitecss.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Styles/')); 
});
```

It's specifically this line that doesn't work for me.

```
   .pipe(cssnano())
```

How to solve this, or more how to minify and concat my css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old versions of node don't have `Promise` defined (it's a new feature of ES2015).

Update your node installation.